# Forward Client IP in Node.JS (net) proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sockets

I'd like to forward the client IP on my proxy to the remote host, so the remote host receives the client's IP, and not my server's IP.

I understand it's not really a proxy at that point, but that's not really what I'm aiming for.

Let's say the remote is 1.1.1.1, client is 2.2.2.2 and my proxy is 3.3.3.3

When the client (2.2.2.2) connects to my server (3.3.3.3), It redirects to the remote (1.1.1.1) but the remote gets the request from IP 3.3.3.3 and not 2.2.2.2, is there a way to "Forward the IP" so the remote doesn't recognize it's been through another server?
Here is how I'm forwarding connections right now where `destip` is equal to the remote server, `destport` is the remote port, `data` is equal to the client > proxy socket, and `socket` is equal to the  proxy > client socket

```
   socket.connect(parseInt(destport), destip, function () {
        socket.on('data', (proxy_client_data) => {
            data.write(proxy_client_data)
        })
        data.on('data', (client_proxy_data)=> {
            socket.write(client_proxy_data)
        })
    })
```

Thanks

Comment: No. Your proxy can voluntarily forward the information of where the request came from, typically in the `Forwarded-For` HTTP header. But it can't hide the fact that the request comes from it. You can't spoof the source IP of a TCP/IP packet, period. Unless you don't care about the response of course, but I'd presume your proxy also wants to receive the response.

Comment: @deceze, I understand that, I don't want to spoof the IP.
I want to make the server recognize the connecting IP as the client's IP, for instance, on the output of a server: Instead of this:
`Information received from (proxy ip)`
I want this:
`Information received from (client ip)`

Comment: That depends on where the server is looking for the IP. If it's telling you the actual source of the request it receives: that can only be your proxy's IP. But if it voluntarily looks for `Forwarded-For` headers as well, then you can pass that information along this way. But that means the server will be explicitly aware that the request comes from a proxy, you can't pretend otherwise.